# Unresolved reference: isChecked

Tags: android, kotlin, ischecked

[image]I tried to add an element to my val, but the element 'isChecked' does not exist. I have added id 'kotlin-android-extensions' in Build.Gradle of my app Module

Comment: What is the type of your `rbbiasa`? Is it a `Switch`, `ToogleButton`?

Comment: @DarShan is a RadioButton

Comment: Can you show where you've declared the same?

Comment: Can you post your XML layout and the part of the class where you instantiate/initialize the `RadioButton` elements?